# CLI ouput shows � locally, but works fine on server

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to read a csv file encoded with ISO-8859-1 with this code

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
     $content = file_get_contents($fn);
      return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
          mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}

$csvData = file_get_contents_utf8("./example_files/file.csv") or die("Failed to load");

print_r($csvData);
```

After trying x number of times with different functions like iconv etc and always getting the same result with output containing � instead of æ/ø/å, I tried running the code on my coworker's computer and a server and both worked perfectly returning correct characters.

So my question is, what are some reasons it might not work on my computer?

**EDIT**

Me and my co-worker use mac. Server is ubuntu. 
Csv file displayed characters correct with windows1252 encoding in sublime, but not with windows1252 encoding in vscode.

$LC_CTYPE outputs UTF-8

hexdump: https://pastebin.com/9BBjkCKh

Comment: check the character set of your terminal...

Comment: Compare php version and character encoding in PHP `mb_internal_encoding();`

Comment: Windows or Unix?

Comment: Unix. Me and my co-worker is using mac. Server is ubuntu.
I've been working from home last couple of days, will update with terminal character set when I'm back at the office. Tomorrow probably :) 

One weird thing is when I opened the csv in sublime on my office computer the characters displayed properly with windows1252 encoding in the bottom right. 
However in vscode with windows1252 encoding I got �.

Thank you for your responses

Comment: If you are seeing � somewhere, it will help to pipe the output of your script to `hexdump -C`, to see which bytes PHP is actually generating.

Comment: echo $LC_CTYPE outputs UTF-8

Comment: Try to get all unknowns clear here: inspect the file with a hex editor and confirm that the bytes of the characters represent text encoded in ISO-8859. Don't use `mb_detect_encoding`, instead specifically convert the content from the known ISO-8859 to UTF-8. Confirm the bytes have been converted correctly, again with a hex editor or the abovementioned `hexdump`. If all those things work correctly, then the only remaining issue could be your terminal.

Comment: Here's hexdump -c result
https://pastebin.com/9BBjkCKh